# How do I run a project in eclipse with different jboss-ejb-client.properties

Tags: eclipse, jboss

I have EJBs deployed on several different servers, for different environments. I have many projects that use these EJBs. I usually just run my projects against the DEV server EJBs, but sometimes I need to run against the TEST or PROD environment EJBs. This necessitates having to comment out all of the DEV nodes in my jboss-client-ejb.properties file and uncomment all of the TEST nodes. But then if I forget to change them back, I may mess up some data if I run it later. What I would like to do is create a different runtime configuration for each environment, and have each runtime config use a different version of the jboss-client-ejb.properties. Is there a way to do this? If so how? I have looked at all of properties of a run configuration, and don't see anything helpful.

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse preferences search for string variable substitution. Here create variables that point to multiple config files for each of your environments. Then create multiple run configurations and for each one (like dev or prod) add a program argument that points to your string variable defined in your preferences like this -DmyconfigFile={$MyDevPropertiesFilePath}, or you could hard code the config path and have multiple runtime configurations that use different config files. Key point here is create multiple runtime launch configurations for each environment and add the properties for each environment that point to the config file respective to each environment. This way you can easily select the launch menu and decide to run "dev" "prod" or whatever you name your multiple configurations. Trying to do this with one runtime configuration will cause pain as you say, because it is easy to forget to revert or change the config file you want to to use. Hope that helps. Also if you create  a new workspace you can export your runtime configurations using the export wizard which is also helpful for passing on to other developers or putting in source control.

P.S Looking more at your question you wan to pass in the config file path as a program argument, you are correct there are no specific options for setting this file path. Using program arguments with multiple launch configurations.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't quite work for me, as I don't specify the name of the file, it has to be the same. I don't even load it in the program, the JBoss client jars do that. The only thing I'm supposed to do is put the jboss-client-ejb.properties on the classpath. So I figured that I can create alternate "resources" folders and put those in the run configuration.